# Why do my Outlook rules sometimes work and sometimes not?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

Here are three example rules I have (in order of execution):

1. If mail in inbox AND mail from Bitbucket AND text body contains "APPROVED", play sound "windows print complete". Only execute on this PC. (because Outlook only allows local rules to have sounds)
2. If mail in inbox AND mail from Bitbucket AND text body contains "APPROVED", move mail to "important". Finish executing rules.
3. If mail in inbox AND mail from Bitbucket, move mail to "unimportant". Finish executing rules.
   There are a few more Bitbucket rules for being assigned as a reviewer (+1 for the sound) and for receiving a comment (+1 for sound) between rules 2 and 3 in my actual setup, but the important thing for now is: there are no rules for pushes on a branch or a status change to MERGED.

**The problem**: Usually, when I log in to work and start up Outlook, I find almost all Bitbucket mails in my "important" folder, even though most of them don't fit my filter. When I receive more mails with Outlook opened, they (at first!) also get filtered in the important folder by error but (I think) after a few hours of online time the rules actually start working again by themselves.

Not only that: if I manually select the "important" folder and tell Outlook to process all mails in that folder with all my BitBucket rules, they actually get sorted correctly! How does that happen and how do I fix it?

Comment: Are you guys running an Exchange service?  Or just regular SMTP?  If it's the former, you'd likely see better results using Flow to run the automation instead.

Answer (score 0):

> When I receive more mails with Outlook opened, they (at first!) also get filtered in the important folder by error but (I think) after a few hours of online time the rules actually start working again by themselves.

Do you mean that when you run the rules manually, the rules can work successfully?

If so, considering they can work after a few hours of online time, i'm afraid that the issue may be related to the corruption of send/receive settings file. You can try to reset the SRS file to check if there're any differences.(Go to C:\Users%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Outlook>Rename the Outlook.srs file to Outlook.srs.old>restart Outlook)

Comment: If I run the rules manually they ALWAYS work, yes. But if I don't run them manually but instead just wait for a random time with Outlook open, it might also pick up on the actual rules and filter correctly. Sometimes it doesn't even after some time. Edit: will try tomorrow, thx!

Comment: I just renamed the file and restarted. It loaded all rules just like I had saved them last time. So... theoretically everything should've been fine.

Comment: If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.